# Exchange integration when inner integrals limit depends on outer

Tags: integration

$$\int_a^b \int_y^b f(x) f(y) dx dy$$

I want to interchange these integrals, but the problem is that $y$ shows up in the limit of inner integral.

What can I do?

Comment: why do you want to interchange them? all you can do is to take $f(y)$ outside of the first integral.

Comment: Draw a picture of the domain of integration.

Comment: @Yanko Good point; I didn't even look at the integrand.

Answer (score 0):

The region $[a,b]\times[a,b]$ is the rectangular region in the $(x,y)$ plane.

The triangular region inside this rectangle that is below the diagonal $x=y$ is the region of integration.

The triangular region can be described as the region for which $x\ge y$, $y\in [a,b]$.  It can also be described by the region $y\le x$, $x\in [a,b]$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.

Comment: @saei Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. If it was not useful, then I can simply delete this answer if you prefer.